# How do you get a custom object to show up in the Interface Builder object palette?

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface-builder, xcode4, xib

I have been trying to create a custom object and have it appear in the object palette so I can drag and drop it into the .xib file when I am building an iOS app. I cannot find any tutorials or instructions online on how to do this; did Apple remove this functionality? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is what was called `IBPlugins` (Interface Builder Plugin). Unfortunately Apple killed it with iOS and since Xcode 4 in general. Shame.

Answer (score 4):

You can't add custom plugins when using the iOS platform. This is possible for normal MacOS development but sadly not for iOS. If however you have a UIView descendent for example, drag a normal UIView onto the screen and change the class to your custom class to use it HOWEVER you will get no design-time view of the custom control.... :(

Comment: Thank you for the expedient response. Now I can stop banging my head against a dead end